# Как сделать ProgressDialog модальным?

Tags: android

Создаю в AsyncTask ProgressDialog, как сделать его модальным?

Comment: это как? в отдельном окне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Таким образом, диалог можно будет удалить только программно. Ни нажатие за границей диалога, ни нажатие кнопки назад не будет действовать.